# Tiny icons from apps on macOS dock

Tags: macos

For some reason, when I have something like messages open in my phone, sometimes it appears in the dock but instead of the normal way it is extremely small. I saw a post that said you can us `killall Dock` to fix it, which worked, but I have seen this multiple times and don't want to have to keep doing it again and again. Is there a permanent fix (it's not that much effort but I'm just wondering), or why does this happen in the first place?

[image: tiny dock icons with cursor for scale]